# str encoding from latin-1 to utf-8 arbitrarily

Tags: string, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have some code that grabs strings from one environment and reproduces them in another.  I am using Python 3.5.  I keep running into this kind of error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in
>   position 112: Body ('–') is not valid Latin-1. Use
>   body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

...and I want to avoid it.  This error is coming from the requests module.  The problem is that I am dealing with literally tens of thousands of strings and new ones are added all the time.  People are cutting and pasting from Excel and whatnot - and have no idea what characters I will bump into so I can't just run a `str.replace()`.  I would like to make sure that every string I get from environment 1 is properly utf-8 encoded before I send it to environment 2.

I tried `str('yadayada').encode('utf-8).decode('utf-8)` and that didn't work.  I tried `str('yadaya', 'utf-8')` and that didn't work.  I tried declaring `"# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-"` and that didn't work.

Comment: what do you do to ensure that they're all utf8 when you receive them?

Comment: I tried what I said in the post: I tried 'yadayada'.encode('utf-8).decode('utf-8) and that didn't work. I tried str('yadaya', 'utf-8') and that didn't work. I tried declaring "# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-" and that didn't work.  I get the strings from a call to a server so I'm just getting an object back.  That object has a name attribute and that's what I'm grabbing from the object.  But I have no control over what the value of that name attribute is and the people making the objects are just customers or non-technical people who cut and paste these names from emails, Excel, whatever.

Answer (score 23):

In Python3 the standard string is utf-8 so there is no encoding like in python2. The problem with *requests* attempts to auto-encode the data for transfer. And fallback is latin1 (or perhaps just first 127 characters of it). In order to give requests enough information, you should encode it.

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/text; charset=utf-8'}
requests.post(url,data = text.encode('utf-8'), headers = headers)
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  Gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message at the start of the post, (a) you have a unicode string (which contains among other characters the character \u2013) and (b) you are trying to encode it as Latin-1. (a) is good. (b) is bad, you should encode it as utf-8.

So, what you need to send is

```
input_data.encode('utf-8')
```

There seems to be a problem also with unwanted or bogus input. This is NOT something that you can fix by fiddling with encodings. You probably need to maintain a dictionary of deletions and substitutions. This requires management assistance to get off the ground. It needs to be done on first input to a database.

By the way, data encoded in Latin-1 doesn't exist in the real world, if you need to work on legacy data, decode using windows-1252 or similar instead of latin1.