# azure cognitive services tts python language="ar-SY" get error : 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position :Body ( )is not valid Latin-1

Tags: python, azure, service

Coding with Python and using azure cognitive services text to speech. I have Arabic text, and I want to generate the corresponding mp3 speech audio :

```
input_text="هذا المحتوى مجاني، لذلك لدعم القناة لمزيد من المحتوى المجاني، يرجى الاشتراك، مثل، مشاركة، تعليق"

  def generate_speech(self,language_id, input_text, outfile, token):
    url = "https://{}.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1".format(self.azure_location)
    print("input_text:"+input_text)
    header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+str(token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml',
    'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'audio-24khz-160kbitrate-mono-mp3'
        }
    data = "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='ar-SY'>\
          <voice xml:lang='ar-SY' xml:gender='Male' name='ar-SY-LaithNeural'>\
            {}\
          </voice>\
          </speak>".format(input_text)
    try:
      response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data)
      response.raise_for_status()
      with open(outfile, "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
      print(response)
      response.close()
    except Exception as e:  
      print("ERROR: ", e)
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 127-129: Body ('هذا') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you
> want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Can you make sure that the indentation of your code is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['latin-1' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65582001/latin-1-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: [str encoding from latin-1 to utf-8 arbitrarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030128/str-encoding-from-latin-1-to-utf-8-arbitrarily), ['latin-1' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769797/latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character-u2019), [How to fix "latin-1 codec can't encode characters in position" in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298260/how-to-fix-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-in-requests), and [UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1822)

Comment: Hi @Babel8Business, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 127-129: Body ('هذا') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

Kindly note that you are `providing the arabic string directly into a variable and asking to print the string, but python does not understand the arabic font or language, that's why it is returning this Unicode error`. To print in arabic, we need to install **arabic_reshaper module** or you can **define it as u"ذهب الطالب الى المدرسة".**

You can refer this SO Thread answer mentioned below to print in Arabic: -

***[how to print Arabic text correctly in PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243215/how-to-print-arabic-text-correctly-in-python/57941725#57941725)***

You can also follow the below article by ***@Divakar V*** for text to speech generation: -

***https://www.divakar-verma.com/post/azure-cognitive-services-using-python-rest-api-text-to-speech***